# Creating UI in GWT application

Tags: gwt

I am making a web application using GWT. Please help me decide what I should use for creating the UI as I have options of creating simple HTML controls, Java widgets and Javascript code.  Please list the pros and corns of all three methods for designing UI in GWT.

Comment: You're not asking a specific question.  The "What should I use" question, in the absence of very specific requirements, is vague and open-ended.  See SO's guide to asking good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT offers the UiBinder for the ui design. If your application isn't too dynamic, I woudld suggest you to use it.

See http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiBinder.html